# Push record to class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class defined as follows:

```
export class Children {
  relationship: string;
  firstname: string;
  middlename: string;
  lastname: string;
  gender: string;
  dob: string;
  ssn: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  zip: string;
  disabled: string;
}
```

Which Im importing into my .ts file.

Also, I have initialized it as follows:

```
public children: Children[]=[];
```

But when trying to add a record, I get the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'child.relationship = this.chrelationship')

Here is the code I am utilizing to push the record:

```
SaveChildren(): void {
    
    let child: Children;
    child.relationship=this.chrelationship;
    child.firstname=this.chfirstname;
    child.lastname=this.chlastname;
    child.middlename=this.chmiddlename;
    child.gender=this.chgender;
    child.dob=this.chdob;
    child.ssn=this.chssn;
    child.phone=this.chphone;
    child.email=this.chemail;
    child.address1=this.chaddress;
    child.address2=this.chaddress2;
    child.city=this.chcity;
    child.state=this.chstate;
    child.zip=this.chzip;
    child.disabled=this.chdisabled;
    this.children.push(child);

    console.log(this.children)

  }
```

Im not able to figure out what am I doing wrong...

Comment: This `let child: Children;` might need to be something like this `let child = new Children();`

Comment: That worked perfect Richard. Thanks so much.